# _*.h files on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I was wondering if someone could explain to me what the _*.h files represent on Mac OS (I assume private-esque header files). I had a student tonight (so not my machine, I don't use Mac), and gcc barfed because it couldn't find sys/_endian.h (which stemmed from including sys/types.h). After looking in his include dir, I found types.h and endian.h, but no _endian.h. There were other _*.h files in there, but no _endian.h. I did a `find` over his user directory, and still couldn't find the file.

I also noticed that the files all had Apple's header/copyright on them...what's up with that? I'm wondering if something he installed could have jumbled these files. Is that even possible? It at least looked like Xcode had appended a --prefix flag (yes, I did a find over those dirs as well, no luck). I've never really ran into a problem before where gcc couldn't find header files required for an include directive for such a popular header file, like `#include <sys/types.h>`. On top of everything, I'm not that familiar with Mac OS X. Has anyone run into any problems like this before, or know where to point me to the right solution?

**Note:** I tried downloading the source for _endian.h, as this seemed like the simplest solution, but the all the links I've found seem to be dead. I can almost guarantee this was a poor idea though, because I'm sure there was some other misplaced header (`#include <sys/types.h>` was the first line in his .c file).

Comment: Can't shed much light on your question, but it sounds like to me your student doesn't have the whole Xcode environment installed. If he's been developing code fine up until now then clearly I'm wrong but as far as I know I've never had a problem including `sys/types.h`. I'm not logged into my Mac partition now, but I just searched the hard drive and found several `types.h`, including `/usr/include/sys/types.h`. I am using an older version of OS X, but I had to install all the XCode stuff and `gcc` manually, it didn't come preinstalled. I can verify when I logon to Mac side.

Comment: [Here's a `<sys/endian.h>` that I found](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/_endian.h). Hopefully it works for your student. That aside, I agree with yano, so I'd request that your student uninstall and reinstall Xcode since it's the easiest solution. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks guys! I figured reinstalling Xcode would be the answer, which I told him to do. Just thought someone else might have had the issue :).